# External monitor support for Sandy Bridge integrated graphics

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have a Lenovo W520 with an I7 2720QM+Nvidia Quadro 2000M.

Now, I always use the system in integrated graphics mode, but I've found that with this setup, the system doesn't detect external monitors attached via the VGA socket - it does detect them using discrete graphics.

Is there something I can do?
What if use a WDMI cable?
Would the drivers at http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q3.html solve this problem (assuming I update to Oneric)?

Comment: did you try using the official nvidia drivers? using nvidia-xsettings, it is quite easy to see which screens the nvidia card can see

Answer (score 1):

There should be no error with the intel cpu built-in card, but if you wish to use the nVidia instead, use "bbswitch" and if your graphic card is optimus, you should use "bumblebee" too